# Awk - Count Each Unique Value and Match Values Between Two Files without printing all feilds of matched line

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have two files. First I am trying to get the count of each unique field in column 4.

And then match the unique field value from the 2nd column of the 2nd file.

File1 - column 4's each unique value and File2 - columns 2 contains the value that I need to match between the two files

So essentially, I am trying to -> take each unique value and value count from column 4 from File1, if there is a match in column2 of file2

File1

```
1 2 3 6 5 

2 3 4 5 1

3 5 7 6 1

2 3 4 6 2

4 6 6 5 1
```

File2

```
1 2 3 hello "6"

1 3 3 hi "5"
```

needed output

```
total count of hello,6 : 3

total count of hi,5 : 2
```

My test code

`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$4]++}NR!=FNR{gsub(/"/,"",$2);b[$2]=$0}END{for( i in b){printf "Total count of %s,%d : %d\n",gensub(/^([^ ]+).*/,"\\1","1",b[i]),i,a[i]}}' File1 File2`

I believe I should be able to do this with awk, but for some reason I am really struggling with this one.

Thanks

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 have put the not working test code pls check, thanks

Comment: None of these worked for you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469676/awk-count-each-unique-value-and-match-values-between-two-files

Comment: I don't unerstand your explanation what you attempt to do. You try to match the second column of the second file with the 4th column of the first file ... but if I look at that, the result should be empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  count[$4]++
  next
}
{
  gsub(/"/,"",$NF)
}
($NF in count){
  print "total count of "$(NF-1)","$NF" : "count[$NF]
}
' file1 file2
```

Sample output will be as follows.

```
total count of hello,6 : 3
total count of hi,5 : 2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{               ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1 is being read.
  count[$4]++          ##Creating array count with index of 4th field and keep increasing its value with 1 here.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  gsub(/"/,"",$NF)     ##Globally substituting " with NULL in last field of current line.
}
($NF in count){        ##Checking condition if last field is present in count then do following.
  print "total count of "$(NF-1)","$NF" : "count[$NF]
                       ##Printing string 2nd last field, last field : and count value here as per request.
}
' file1 file2          ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: @Nithin justin, I had rejected your edit in my answer because that should go to comments section like I am commenting now, please check my edited answer now, it has that text `total count of ` too now, cheers.